# Get rid of duplicate lines in SQL result set

Tags: sql, select, db2, resultset

I have 2 tables which I use to get a result set from

```
select 
a.id,
a.test,
a.score,
b.name,
b.person,
b.grade
from table_test a, table_pers b 
where a.test=b.test
```

now the problem is that table b has multiple entries which are all the same but for "passed"... now if passed is yes and no to 1 person I only need the yes result row and only that one otherwise I need the no row and only onw of them if there are multiple.

Any idea on how that could work?

Thanks in advance.

Ok since the case doens't like the group by here is a more detailed view on the select:

```
select
t.id,
t.tests test,
t.lang,
m.title_TEXT Titel, 
m.Sched Schedual,
m.prof profs, 
m.date_out Date,
m.sub subject,
m.chan Changes, 
case
when m.cha2 = ''
then m.cha1
else m.cha2
end as last_change,
case
when m.datac2 = ''
then m.datac1
else m.datac2
end as Change_date,         
t.posp,
t.A1,
t.B1,
t.Failed,
t.analy,         
t.vect,
t.cover,
t.typ,
t.circ,
t.deadline
from table_test t, table_pers m where m.test=t.test
```

The values I look at in t.passed are '1A' and '1B' 
If there is a 1A then then I need that row if tehre is only 1B then I need one of those rows.

The complete select has 39 fields.. but those missing are just normal selects no cases or things like that.

Comment: What I haven't seen addressed yet is, when there are multiple rows exactly which row do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that `'Yes' > 'No'`, so you could just use:

```
select  a.id,
        a.test,
        a.score,
        b.name,
        b.person,
        b.grade,
        MAX(Passed) AS Passed
from    table_test a
        INNER JOIN table_pers b 
            ON a.test = b.test
GROUP BY a.id, a.test, a.score, b.name, b.person, b.grade;
```

N.B. I have switched your ANSI 89 JOINs to the new ANSI 92 JOIN syntax. [This article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) covers some good reasons for doing so, however it is subjective and the choice is ultimately yours, the result is the same either way.

An alternative, and possibly more rubust solution (if you have other different allowed values for `passed`) would be:

```
select  a.id,
        a.test,
        a.score,
        b.name,
        b.person,
        b.grade,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN Passed = 'Yes' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS Passed
from    table_test a
        INNER JOIN table_pers b 
            ON a.test = b.test
GROUP BY a.id, a.test, a.score, b.name, b.person, b.grade;
```

---

**EDIT**

There is no reason I know of that CASE won't work in a group by (unless you are using the alias in the group by and not the full case statement), however you could also achieve this using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (   SELECT  t.id,
                    t.tests test,
                    t.lang,
                    m.title_TEXT Titel, 
                    m.Sched Schedual,
                    m.prof profs, 
                    m.date_out Date,
                    m.sub subject,
                    m.chan Changes, 
                    case when m.cha2 = '' then m.cha1 else m.cha2 end as last_change,
                    case when m.datac2 = ''then m.datac1 else m.datac2 end as aenderungsdatumChange_date,      
                    t.posp,
                    t.A1,
                    t.B1,
                    t.Failed,
                    t.analy,         
                    t.vect,
                    t.cover,
                    t.typ,
                    t.circ,
                    t.deadline,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.ID ORDER BY t.Passed) AS rn
            from    table_test t
                    INNER JOIN table_pers m 
                        ON m.test = t.test
        ) t
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: Do I have to group over everything? The complet select has 39 terms :-(
I didn't know that yes has that kind of advantage, this values I use are 1A and 1B where 1A would be the yes.

Comment: maybe I should also mention that there are 2 case statements within the select .. and the group by doesn't work on those.

Comment: the db2 command line tool doesn't seem to like it. Throws an exception there

Comment: can you post a query which is throwing exception?

Comment: select
    t.id,
    t.tests test, 
    case
    when m.cha2 = ''
    then m.cha1
    else m.cha2
    end as last_change,
    case
    when m.datac2 = ''
    then m.datac1
    else m.datac2
    end as Change_date,      
    t.posp
    from table_test t, table_pers m where m.test=t.test
    group by t.id, t.tests, last_change, Change_date,t.posp

Comment: WOW that new solution you wrote worked.... great thanks so much. Now I just need to read about the rownumber() and partition by statement.. new for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
select  a.id,
        a.test,
        a.score,
        b.name,
        b.person,
        b.grade,
        Passed
from    table_test a
        INNER JOIN table_pers b 
            ON a.test = b.test
    where qualify row_number() over (partition by a.id order by passed desc)=1;
```